# Make load variable private

Tags: javascript, jsom

I have the following function which retrieves the current user's properties:

```
function helper_redirect(){

        this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();


        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(this.clientContext);

        personProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

        this.clientContext.load(personProperties);

        this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));

    }
```

When I type in the console `personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['SID'];` it returns the current user's SID.

**How can I make this variable not accessible in the console?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variable inside your function.

Right now you are missing the the `var`part in front of its first appearance in your snippet, which means one of two things:

1. You have declared it elsewhere in your code and needs to protect it there
2. This is the first mention of it and you are not using the `var` for declaration of it, which leads to it being interpreted as a global variable by the JavaScript engine

Comment: When I add var in front of personProperties it gives me TypeError: personProperties is undefined in the success function. How can I send the  variable to the success function? Many thanks.

Comment: I found out how to do it, I just send the variable as a parameter to the success function